# how to get the edit text value out of an editable listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I created an editable custom listview with a button outside the listview. I want to save the editText value entered by the user on the button click. My edit text is in base Adapter class and my list and button is in activity class, i'm having problem accessing the edit text from the list and my code crashes because of null pointer exception

```
public class ProductsList  extends Activity{

ProductListAdapter dataAdapter;
ProgressDialog progressDialog=null;
ListView listView;
UserSQLiteDB usersqlite_obj;
ArrayList<Products> prodlist;
EditText edChemistName, edChemistAddr; 
Button btnSave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productlist); 

    edChemistName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edChemistAddr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btnSave =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    usersqlite_obj = new UserSQLiteDB(this);
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Saved","Please wait...", true);
    //  new Thread() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            try{
                usersqlite_obj.open();
                prodlist = new ArrayList<Products>();
                prodlist = usersqlite_obj.getProductsList();
                Log.e("prodlist", "1");
                dataAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(ProductsList.this,prodlist);
                listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                usersqlite_obj.close(); 

            }  catch (Exception e) {

                Log.d("error",e.getMessage());
            }
            dismissLoadingDialog();
    }
    });  

}
  public void buttonClick(View V) {

        for(int i=0;i<listView.getCount();i++){

               View row = listView.getChildAt(i);
               Log.e("editText clicked", "yes");
               EditText editText= (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.ed);
               if (editText.length()>0){
                   String text = editText.getText().toString();
                   Log.e("extracted text", "text");
               }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to use edittext data of listview in ur adapter class then u should pass this liatview in adapter class or you can set this adapter in activty file.